# What' s going on with this program?

Tags: emacsclient

I have been using emacs for many years, but from version 26 ... there is a mess with server as I have to type emacsclient in place of simply emacs. Going worse with 27.

From 26 I haven't found a way to disable server mode ...
From 27 emacsclient allows me to open only one session at a time ... I received message showing `type CTRL # when you have finished` ... while the file I try to open in another shell is asking me to Wait.

It's not fine at all.

How can I get the old behaviour ? I don't need server mode by default. I just need that `emacs -nw` opens my file without messing ...

Comment: I haven't noticed any change in the behaviour. Can you describe in more detail what you expect and how the current behaviour differs to it?

Comment: When I try to open file with "emacs myfile", it's getting back to command line. I can see a process emacs daemon running. Then I must open my file using emacsclient. From 27.1, i can open only one emacsclient at once. The second one asks me to wait.

I want to type emacs myfile ... it' s opening without talking server and so on. The old behaviour ...

Comment: That's not what I see. What does `type emacs` output?

Comment: Please put all clarifications into the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you use switch `Q` when you run `emacs` or `emacsclient`? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Solution (it's silly) : Oh_my_zsh defined an alias launching the daemon mode by default. I had to disable the call to emacs plugin in my .zshrc

See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/emacs for details.